# Best way to show popular posts in wordpress without plugin

Tags: wordpress

i want to show popular posts in my wordpress theme
i'm using this functions for post views:

```
function getPostViews($postID){
$count_key = 'post_views_count';
$count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
if($count==''){
    delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
    add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
return "0 view";
}
return $count.' views';
}


function setPostViews($postID) {
$count_key = 'post_views_count';
$count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
if($count==''){
    $count = 0;
    delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
    add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
}else{
$count++;
update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
}
}
```

so how i can do that? i want to show 5 most popular posts with views. and also is this a good way or not?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the most popular posts using following code:
`

```
$args  = array(
    "post_type" => "post",
    "post_status" => "publish",
    "posts_per_page" => 5,
    "meta_key" => "post_views_count",
    "orderby" => "meta_value_num",
    "order" => "DESC"
);
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

To get the view count you just need to use:

`get_post_meta($postid, "post_views_count", true)`